# Does the simplicity lemma of Koenig's theorem applied to $t-\frac{f(t)}{\frac{d}{dt}f(t)}$ indiciate the simplicity of the roots of f?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, function-and-relation-composition, riemann-hypothesis, complex-dynamics

Koenigs Linearization Theorem: If the magnitude (absolute value) of the multiplier $\lambda = \dot{f} (0)$ of a holomorphic map $f$ is not strictly equal to 0 or 1, that is $λ \ne \{0, 1 \}$, then a local holomorphic change of coordinates $w = \phi(z)$, called the Koenig's function, unique up to a scalar multiplication by nonzero constant, exists, having a fixed-point at the origin $\phi (0) = 0$ such that Schrοder's equation is true
$\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{- 1} = \lambda w \forall w \in \varepsilon_0$
for some neighborhood $\varepsilon_0$ of the origin 0.

The Simplicity Lemma: The Koenig's function $\phi$ is the only solution to the eigenvalue equation as all of the other solutions are constant multiples of powers of the principal eigenfunction $\sigma(t)$ of $C_\phi$

My question is: if the (Schroeder iteration) function φ is the Newton map
$$t-\frac{f(t)}{\frac{d}{dt}f(t)}$$ does the simplicity lemma tell us anything about the multiplicity of the root of f which is the fixed-point to which the Koenigs function converges?

It does not tell us that the root of f has multiplicity one because for instance if we let
$f (t) = \tanh (\ln (1 - t^2))$ then its easy to see that f has a double-root at the origin (factor the function into a rational function of two finite products
$$f(t)=\frac{(1-t^2)^2-1}{(1-t^2)^2+1}  $$

However, if we take the composite function $g(t)=f(g(t))$ then the mapping $f(t)$ converts roots of multiplicity 1 to roots of multiplicity 2, and thus makes Koenig linearization applicable to functions with super-attractive fixed-points at the points where there are roots of multiplicity one .

Does there exist some way to say that if the Newton map of the composite function $f(g(t))$ has a geometrically attracting fixed-point of multiplier 1/2 then the root at that point of $g(t)$ indeed is simple with multiplicity one?

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the "multiplicity one" lemma of Koenig's operators and the simplicity of roots of a function can be established through the theory of spectral analysis and differential geometry applied to the Riemann surface associated with the function g(x).

The Riemann surface associated with the function g(x) is the complex plane with branch cuts along the real axis, where the function takes on complex values. The Riemann surface is a two-dimensional manifold that has a natural metric, which is induced by the complex plane. The Laplace-Beltrami operator on this manifold can be expressed in terms of Koenig's operators, which are integral operators acting on the space of automorphic forms.

The iteration function h(x) = x - g(x)/g'(x) can be viewed as a map from the Riemann surface to itself, which preserves the metric and the orientation. The roots of f(x) correspond to the fixed points of h(x), which are points on the Riemann surface where h(x) = x. The fixed points of h(x) are critical points of the potential function V(x) = g(x)^2/2, which is related to the energy of a classical particle moving on the Riemann surface under the influence of the potential.

The simplicity of the roots of f(x) is related to the Morse index of the critical points of V(x), which is a measure of the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of V(x) at the critical point. The Morse index is equal to the number of negative eigenvalues of the Laplacian on the Riemann surface in the neighborhood of the critical point, which is determined by the "multiplicity one" lemma of Koenig's operators.

In particular, if the Laplacian has no negative eigenvalues in the neighborhood of a critical point, then the critical point is a non-degenerate minimum of V(x), and the corresponding root of f(x) is a simple root. Conversely, if the Laplacian has at least one negative eigenvalue in the neighborhood of a critical point, then the critical point is a degenerate minimum or a saddle point of V(x), and the corresponding root of f(x) is not simple.

To apply this theory to the function g(x) = tanh(ln(1+f(x)^2)), one needs to compute the Laplacian on the Riemann surface associated with g(x), which can be done using the Riemann-Roch theorem and the theory of automorphic forms. Then, one needs to analyze the critical points of the potential function V(x) = g(x)^2/2 and compute their Morse indices to determine the simplicity of the roots of f(x).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).